# Access IndexPath.row outside of didSelectRowAt indexPath function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am defining this in a UIViewController and trying to access myIndex in a different view controller. How can I do this?

I would like to do this programmatically without storyboards. Any help is much appreciated!

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
        let myIndex = indexPath.row
    }
```

Comment: The different view controller, if it's pushed or presented, then you can pass data from didSelectRow. Otherwise, use a sharedInstance to pass data between different controllers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access from anywhere of your project you can store the data in userdefault. inside your didSelectRowAt set the indexPath.row using key myIndex , this key should be unique:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath.row, forKey: "myIndex")
```

Then retrieve the data from any viewController:

```
If UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myIndex")!=nil{
    let savedIndexPath = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "myIndex")
}
```

Comment: Mhmmmmmm! Thanks! This did the trick. You're the man.

Comment: welcome Mike Perhats

Comment: @Mike Perhats if this answer solve your problem please accept it as a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

**You have to consider passing Indexpath like this:**

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextView", sender: indexPath)

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any) {
    let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
    let eventStruct =  post[indexPath.row]
    let secondViewController = segue.destination as? NextViewController
    secondViewController?.data = sender as AnyObject 
}
```